# Apache ProxyPassMatch loop request

Tags: regex, apache, proxypass

I have the instruction below on Apache configuration:

```
ProxyPass "/info" unix:/var/run/docker.sock|http://localhost/info
ProxyPass "/version" unix:/var/run/docker.sock|http://localhost/version
ProxyPass "/containers/json" unix:/var/run/docker.sock|http://localhost/containers/json
ProxyPassMatch "^/containers/([^/]+)/json$" unix:/var/run/docker.sock|http://localhost/containers/$1/json
ProxyPass / "!"
```

Requests below works fine:

```
http://server.domain/info
http://server.domain/version
http://server.domain/containers/json
```

But this one is not working:

```
http://server.domain/containers/asd123qwe/json
```

I was expecting `ProxyPassMatch` to generate a request like this:

```
http://localhost/containers/asd123qwe/json
```

Is it possible the configuration generates a loop condition?
Should `ProxyPassMatch` generate an internal request on Apache again or simple forward it to socket as instructed in configuration?

Using `log_forensic_module` I get the log as below, that is why I am considering some infinite loop request as the problem. Sorry for the long output!

```
GET /containers/f1063abfd92409/json HTTP/1.1|Host:server.domain%3a8080|Connection:keep-alive|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4
GET /containers/f1063abfd92409/json HTTP/1.1|Host:localhost|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4|X-Forwarded-For:10.255.0.2|X-Forwarded-Host:server.domain%3a8080|X-Forwarded-Server:127.0.0.1|Connection:close
GET /containers/f1063abfd92409/json HTTP/1.1|Host:localhost|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4|X-Forwarded-For:10.255.0.2, 127.0.0.1|X-Forwarded-Host:server.domain%3a8080, localhost|X-Forwarded-Server:127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|Connection:close
GET /containers/f1063abfd92409/json HTTP/1.1|Host:localhost|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4|X-Forwarded-For:10.255.0.2, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|X-Forwarded-Host:server.domain%3a8080, localhost, localhost|X-Forwarded-Server:127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|Connection:close
GET /containers/f1063abfd92409/json HTTP/1.1|Host:localhost|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4|X-Forwarded-For:10.255.0.2, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|X-Forwarded-Host:server.domain%3a8080, localhost, localhost, localhost|X-Forwarded-Server:127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|Connection:close
GET /containers/f1063abfd92409/json HTTP/1.1|Host:localhost|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4|X-Forwarded-For:10.255.0.2, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|X-Forwarded-Host:server.domain%3a8080, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost|X-Forwarded-Server:127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|Connection:close
GET /containers/f1063abfd92409/json HTTP/1.1|Host:localhost|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4|X-Forwarded-For:10.255.0.2, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|X-Forwarded-Host:server.domain%3a8080, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost|X-Forwarded-Server:127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|Connection:close
GET /containers/f1063abfd92409/json HTTP/1.1|Host:localhost|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4|X-Forwarded-For:10.255.0.2, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|X-Forwarded-Host:server.domain%3a8080, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost|X-Forwarded-Server:127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|Connection:close
GET /containers/f1063abfd92409/json HTTP/1.1|Host:localhost|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4|X-Forwarded-For:10.255.0.2, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|X-Forwarded-Host:server.domain%3a8080, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost|X-Forwarded-Server:127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|Connection:close
GET /containers/f1063abfd92409/json HTTP/1.1|Host:localhost|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4|X-Forwarded-For:10.255.0.2, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|X-Forwarded-Host:server.domain%3a8080, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost, localhost|X-Forwarded-Server:127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1|Connection:close
```

Comment: I am no expert in Apache, but your regex should work just fine, so I suggest you to look for the cause of problem wider.

Comment: @DmitryVolkov thanks for your comment, I am trying to do that but I can'f find any place with a good explanation of why it is not working. I agree with you, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
^\/containers\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?\/json$
```

This will lazily match any alphanumeric until the next forwardslash `/`, which is what I assume you want.

Comment: Thanks for your post, you are correct, I want any char until `/`, but I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: @Azize See my edit, I think you need to escape the forward slashes.

Comment: Stil not working, it is very strange. I put parentheses on it, otherwise I am not able to use it on proxy URL. That is the line: `ProxyPassMatch "^\/containers\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+?)\/json$" unix:/var/run/docker.sock|http://localhost/containers/$1/json`

Comment: Oh, well $ is not an alphanumeric character, that's why it's not catching that line. Use [a-zA-Z0-9_$] instead.

Comment: Now I am confuse, why should I use `$` inside the regex? My request does not have it. That is my request example: `http://server.domain:8080/containers/43a0bed33d14/json`

Comment: Well you just wrote an example (with localhost) above which had `$`, so I figured you wanted it. Anyway, try removing the `^` at the start of the regex.

Comment: Aha ... no, it was not an example, it is the proxy address I am using, so all requests to `"^\/containers\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+?)\/json$" ` should be redirect to `unix:/var/run/docker.sock|http://localhost/containers/$1/jso‌​n`. `$1` here is a variable from regex, the one between parentheses.